# infinite families in stable homotopy groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, spectral-sequences

The question is about infinite families in stable homotopy groups. Yes, there are some Q&A about the topic.

But I wonder if the order of Mahowald's elements is known?
in Green Book it mentioned that the order is presumably 4, and less likely is 2,
but what is current situation?

Which elements in ANSS (integral or mod 2) detect them? certain elements of $\beta$-family?

Same questions about Bruner's family.  Lin's family is also interesting (though it has quite high Adam's filtration, but may be its Novikov's filtration is much smaller)